# Apex chart tooltip shared not working if series have different size

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

If my series have different sizes apexchart doesn't render tooltip shared with value with same x point.
Follow codepen

```
var ts2 = 1484418600000;
var dates = [];
var dates2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
  ts2 = ts2 + 86400000;
  var innerArr = [ts2, i * Math.floor(Math.random() * 220)];
  var innerArr2 = [ts2, i * Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)];
  dates.push(innerArr);
  dates2.push(innerArr2);
  
}

dates2.push([ts2 + 86400000, 1000]);
console.log(dates)

var options = {
  chart: {
    type: "line",
    stacked: false,
    height: 250,
    zoom: {
      type: "x",
      enabled: true
    },
    toolbar: {
      autoSelected: "zoom"
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "XYZ MOTORS",
      data: dates
    },{
      name: "asdasd",
      data: dates2
    }
  ],
  markers: {
    size: 0
  },
  title: {
    text: "Stock Price Movement",
    align: "left"
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

https://codepen.io/Fernando-BA-the-animator/pen/XWQjYmX

I want the tooltip shows all series value with same x point.
And I cannot find any solution for this bug, maybe this is an issue with apex chart library.

Comment: not sure if this the best approach but you can try to create series with null values, so you have both series equal in length. see: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/420#issuecomment-570479557 ... so you can add `dates.push([ts2 + 86400000, null])` .. now dates and dates2 arrays have the same size and the shared tooltip should work as expected.